# Add active style to link with Express and Express-Handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

how can i active the link(set different color) in express and express-handlebars. With pure JS it's simple, but i can't write it here ... :(

it's a standart navbar, here's the code:

```
 <ul class="links">
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/warum">Warum</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/was">Was</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/wer">Wer</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/aktuelles">Aktuelles</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/referenzen">Referenzen</a></li>
            {{#if admin}}
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/logout">Ausloggen</a></li>
            {{else}}
            <li><a class="nav-anch" href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
            {{/if}}
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("nav-anch");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

*now in your css file add some styles for the class active*

Comment: i know that, but you can't write plain JS with express ...